# can't start Git after updating Mac OS/XCode

Tags: xcode, git

Recently I update the version of Xcode,but when i run `git` in terminal,the  terminal is giving an error message:

xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk" cannot be located.
git: error: unable to find utility "git", not a developer tool or in PATH

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue related with IntelliJ  , try this:

open terminal and execute:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

Press space until the end, and agree with the licence.
This worked to me,

Best Regards,